# ASP.NET Identity Cookie across subdomains on .Net and Core

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-identity, data-protection

**I have many application which is hosted on main domain and sub domains:**

Website A, ASP.NET (.Net Core 2.0) at www.example.com

Website B, ASP.NET MVC (4.7 .net Framework) at site.example.com

> Website C, ASP.NET **Identity** (.Net Core 2.0) at account.example.com

Website D, ASP.NET Webform (4.7 .net Framework) at file.example.com

I would like to login uses on **account.example.com**, after authenticate users will redirected to other websites. They will be authorize by there roles on other websites.

I'm trying to share a cookie between these websites and all of the website are hosted on **Azure Web App**.

I am using **ASP.NET Identity (.Net Core 2.0)**. I'm using the built-in cookie authentication.

How can I use Data Protection in all application and share cookie among them.

For Data Protection my code is:

```
 services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("example")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"%HOME%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys"))
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```

For Cookie Authentication my code is:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieDomain = ".example.com"
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I got solution from this Microsoft documentation**

[Share cookies among apps with ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

And Sample code for this sub-domain authentication system

[Cookie Sharing Sample App - GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication)

> **The sample illustrates cookie sharing across three apps that use cookie authentication:**

- ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages app without using ASP.NET Core Identity
- ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC app with ASP.NET Core Identity
- ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 MVC app with ASP.NET Identity

> **Put this code in your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDataProtection()
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(GetKeyRingDirInfo())
.SetApplicationName("example");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => 
{   
options.Cookie.Name = "example";
options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
});
```

> For KeyRing method

```
private DirectoryInfo GetKeyRingDirInfo()
    {
        var startupAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var applicationBasePath = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
        do
        {
            directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;

            var keyRingDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, "KeyRing"));
            if (keyRingDirectoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                return keyRingDirectoryInfo;
            }
        }
        while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);

        throw new Exception($"KeyRing folder could not be located using the application root {applicationBasePath}.");
    }
```

> **Note : You have to copy KeyRing file which is automatically generated on Identity application hosting server and manually paste to other sub-domain and main domain hosting server of other website to share cookie for authentication.**

Comment: Where can I find this KeyRing file on auzre app?

Comment: You have to manually create **KeyRing** folder in azure app. Then Identity application will automatically automatically generate Data Protection file. 
Then fallow the above note further instructions for sub-domain and main domain authentication. 
To create KeyRIng folder open **Azure Web App** --> Go to **Advanced Tools** then **GO**.  It will redirect to another portal **Kudu Service** a file explorer of your web app.
In menu **Debug Console** --> open **CMD** --> navigate to **Site** option in file explore and crate the **KeyRing** folder.

Comment: HI
I have two asp.net core 6 websites on the same server
One is on identity.example.fr, the other one is on test.example.fr
on the 2 websites I put this :

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
  .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\DATA"))
  .SetApplicationName("AAA");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
      options.LoginPath = "/login";
      options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.fr";
    });

But if I am logged on identity.example.fr, I am not loged on the other one
What's wrong ?

Comment: The above code is for Live Server Demo, not for localhost. If you would like to test on local server then you have to comment the domain "options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";"

Answer (score 2):

Regarding .Net Core, if you want to share your cookie among several sites, you may try the following to initialize it instead of UseCookieAuthentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication();
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.Name = "CookieName";

    //options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";
    if (!CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        options.Cookie.Domain = CommonConfig.CookieDomain; // ".mydomain.com"

    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;

    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(5 * 30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"); 
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logoff"); 
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"); 


    var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(CommonConfig.PersistKeysStoreC));
    options.DataProtectionProvider = protectionProvider;

    // This adds claims data to the cookie...
    options.Events.OnSignedIn = async (context) =>
        {   
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity identity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;

            UserManager<AppUser> userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            AppUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Principal);
            identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email.ToString()));
            //identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, user.LastName));
            //identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        };
});
```

Of course you will need to give the same ProtectionProvider path for all sites.